# Issues while create a file in shell scripting in jenkins pipeline script

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to create a multi line file in Jenkins pipeline script using the below commands.

```
    sh "echo \"line 1\" >> greetings.txt"
    sh "echo \"line 2\" >> greetings.txt"
    echo "The contents of the file are"
    sh 'cat greetings.text'
    sh 'rm -rf greetings.txt'
```

Unforunately , I am not able to create the file named greetings.txt. Can any one please let me know, where I am going wrong.

Results in Jenkins console:

```
[tagging] Running shell script
+ echo 'line 1'
[Pipeline] sh
[tagging] Running shell script
+ echo 'line 2'
[Pipeline] echo
The contents of the file are
[Pipeline] sh
[tagging] Running shell script
+ cat greetings.text
cat: greetings.text: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solve this by using single quotes with `sh`, so you don't need to use escaping. Also you have to create an initial file with `>` and add content with `>>`:

```
pipeline{
    agent any

    stages{
        stage('write file'){
            steps{
                sh 'echo "line 1" > greetings.txt'
                sh 'echo "line 2" >> greetings.txt'
                echo "The contents of the file is"
                sh 'cat greetings.txt'
                sh 'rm -rf greetings.txt'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
[test] Running shell script
+ echo line 1
[Pipeline] sh
[test] Running shell script
+ echo line 2
[Pipeline] echo
The contents of the file is
[Pipeline] sh
[test] Running shell script
+ cat greetings.txt
line 1
line 2
[Pipeline] sh
[test] Running shell script
+ rm -rf greetings.txt
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not finding a file named `greetings.text` because you didn't create one (a litte typo in the extension in your cat line). Try `sh 'cat greetings.txt'`, or even better adjusted your script:

```
sh "echo \"line 1\" >> greetings.txt"
sh "echo \"line 2\" >> greetings.txt"
echo "The contents of the file are"
sh 'cat greetings.txt'
sh 'rm -rf greetings.txt'
```

If you want to use multiline commands, you can also use this syntax:

```
sh """
echo \"line 1\" >> greetings.txt
echo \"line 2\" >> greetings.txt
echo "The contents of the file are:"
cat greetings.txt
rm -rf greetings.txt
"""
```

From the last example, this should generate an output like:

```
Running shell script
+ echo 'line 1'
+ echo 'line 2'
+ echo 'The contents of the file are:'
The contents of the file are:
+ cat greetings.txt
line 1
line 2
+ rm -rf greetings.txt
```